# Валидация XML средствами ABAP

Tags: xml, валидация, xsd

Добрый день! Возникла необходимость проверять входящие XML документы по XSD схемам. Насколько мне известно, существует способ сделать это средствами XI/PI, но в нашей системе такого нет – решение не подходит.

На ум приходит только «отдельная» утилита на Java или каком-нибудь другому языке, к которой можно будет обращаться с просьбой «проверить этот XML по этой схеме»... Но это сложнее и потенциально менее надёжнее.

Какие готовые решения (стандартные или не очень), на ваш взгляд, можно использовать для решения этой задачи? Комментарии, уточняющие вопросы, предложения и предположения приветствуются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, стандартного пути нет. Но есть обходные пути.
Попробуйте посмотреть вот эту статью, там человек разработал свои классы для валидации и выложил их (SAPLINK).
http://scn.sap.com/blogs/edward.pelyavskyy2/2010/03/09/validating-xml-with-xml-schema-xsd